# unable to filter text in list-view in android

Tags: android

Adapter Class:

```
  public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Datamodel> {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<Datamodel> datamodel;
        ArrayList<Datamodel> productlist;


        public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                List<Datamodel> worldpopulationlist) {
            super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);

            this.context = context;

            this.datamodel = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();

            this.datamodel.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            productlist = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();

            productlist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);

        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView name;

            ImageView flowerimage;
            ImageView share;
            ImageView bookmark;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Datamodel getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return productlist.get(getCount() - position - 1);
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
                //

                holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.flowerimage = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.flowerimage);

                holder.share = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);

                holder.bookmark = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText(datamodel.get(position).getName());
            Picasso.with(context).load(datamodel.get(position).getImagepath())
                    .into(holder.flowerimage);
            holder.flowerimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    imagealert(position);
                }
            });

            // holder.itemnumber.setText("5");
            holder.share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    sharedata(position);
                }

            });
            holder.bookmark.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            return view;
        }

        public void imagealert(int position) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.imagepopulayout);
            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imagepopup);

            String imageUrl = datamodel.get(position).getImagepath();
            Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(image);
            // ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            // image.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash_screen_bg);

            dialog.show();
        }

        public void sharedata(int position) {

            String name = datamodel.get(position).getName();
            String image = datamodel.get(position).getImagepath();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Flower Name:" + name
                    + "Flower Image Path:" + image);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            context.startActivity(sendIntent);
        }


        public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            datamodel.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                datamodel.addAll(productlist);
            } else {
                for (Datamodel wp : productlist) {
                    if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText)) {
                        datamodel.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Actvity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<Datamodel> list = new ArrayList<Datamodel>();

    ListView listview;

    EditText editText1;

    ImageView search;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    DbHelper dbhelper;
    ImageView imageView2;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbhelper = new DbHelper(this);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        search = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        search.setOnClickListener(this);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // dbhelper.insertModfydate("1", "5");

        new a().execute();

         editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int
         arg3) {
         // When user changed the Text
         System.out.println("Text [" + cs + "]");


         }

         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
         int arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }



         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String text = editText1.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
         }
         });

    }

    class a extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String response = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://development.easystartup.org/NO/Backend/flower.php");

                JSONObject _jfuncation = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                String data = _jfuncation.getString("data");

                JSONArray _JsonArray = new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < _JsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    Datamodel datamodel = new Datamodel();

                    JSONObject newjsonobject = _JsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String flowername = newjsonobject.getString("name");
                    String flowerimage = newjsonobject.getString("url");

                    datamodel.setName(flowername);
                    datamodel.setImagepath(flowerimage);

                    list.add(datamodel);

                    Log.d("Response", flowername + "" + flowerimage);

                }

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            String name = sharedpreferences.getString("Falitervalue", "");

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, 1000).show();
            if (name.equals("1")) {

                Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Datamodel>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Datamodel u1, Datamodel u2) {
                        return u2.name.compareToIgnoreCase(u1.name);
                    }
                });

                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.listitem, list);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.listitem, list);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg0.getId() == R.id.search) {
//          adapter.getFilter().filter(editText1.getText().toString());




        } else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.imageView2) {

            String name = sharedpreferences.getString("Falitervalue", "");

            if (name.equals("1")) {
                Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("Falitervalue", "0");

                editor.commit();
                Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Datamodel>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Datamodel u1, Datamodel u2) {
                        return u1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(u2.name);
                    }
                });

                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.listitem, list);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            else {
                Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("Falitervalue", "1");

                editor.commit();

                Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Datamodel>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Datamodel u1, Datamodel u2) {
                        return u2.name.compareToIgnoreCase(u1.name);
                    }
                });

                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.listitem, list);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
    }

}

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
```

I want to filter listview on text basis I want filter list-view or search listview  name wise i have write code but when I try to search it give exception arraylistthrogh index out of bound exception at `holder.name.setText(datamodel.get(position).getName());` this line please tell me where and what am doing wrong I want search name wise only filter listview name wise .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount();
        }
```

Returning `super.getCount()` causing issue, return same data-source count which using for getting data if `getView` method using `position` :

```
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return datamodel.size();
        }
```